# If statements in methods

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, scope

I have a variable set in C# that changes depending on which If statement is selected.

But when I try to Console.WriteLine the variable it tells me the *variable does not exist in the current context*, could someone help me with this please?

```
public void mood()
{
  var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;

  if (unhappiness < 5)
  {
    string m = "Happy";
  }

  if (unhappiness <= 5 && unhappiness <= 10)
  {
    string m = "Okay";
  }

  if (unhappiness <= 11 && unhappiness <= 15)
  {
    string m = "Frustrated";
  }

  if (unhappiness <= 16)
  {
    string m = "Mad";
  }

  Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

The variable 'm' is the one I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Move string m to the top of the method and remve the word string from isnide the ifs.

Comment: You have other issues as well.   Assuming the scoping of m is fixed, this will return Mad for all values <=16 and Happy for all values > 16.

Comment: You can use [if, else if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(v=vs.90).aspx) to fix the issues @ChrisCudmore mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to declare string m outside - after your method decleration:

```
public string mood()
        {
            var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;
            string m = string.Empty;
            if (unhappiness < 5)
            {
                m = "Happy";
            }

            if (unhappiness <= 5 && 
                unhappiness <= 10)
            {
                m = "Okay";
            }

            if (unhappiness <= 11 &&
                unhappiness <= 15)
            {
                m = "Frustrated";
            }

            if (unhappiness <= 16)
            {
                m = "Mad";
            }
            return m;
```

Comment: Just a detail, but returning a string from a void method won't work ;)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
{

}
```

Is putting your variable inside that scope, so it won't be available outside of it. That's why you can declare 4 variables named `m` like you just did. Each `m` is a different guy, inside its little bracket world.

I think you may want to declare it beforehand:

```
string m="";

if (unhappiness < 5)
{
    m = "Happy";
}

if (unhappiness <= 5 && 
    unhappiness <= 10)
{
    m = "Okay";
}

if (unhappiness <= 11 &&
   unhappiness <= 15)
{
    m = "Frustrated";
}

if (unhappiness <= 16)
{
    m = "Mad";
}
```

Comment: Trying to grok c# scope. Looks like what is happening here is that if a variable is declared at the top of a block, and then an assignment happens inside an nested block, the assignment persists outside the inner block. Said another way, to hide a variable in an inner block, I would have to RE-DECLARE it in that block. Correct? Otherwise the variable would still refer to the parent instance.

Answer (score 1):

Define string M before the if-statements.
If you initialize it just after var unhappiness, and set it within the if-statements.
You define string m within the if-statements, but when they end, string m is gone as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
public void mood()
{
    var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;

    string m = string.Empty;

    if (unhappiness < 5)
    {
        m = "Happy";
    }

    if (unhappiness >= 6 && unhappiness <= 10)
    {
        m = "Okay";
    }

    if (unhappiness >= 11 && unhappiness <= 15)
    {
        m = "Frustrated";
    }

    if (unhappiness >= 16)
    {
        m = "Mad";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

The problem was that `m` was defined inside an `if` statement, it scope was limited to that statement.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written, the variable `m` only exists within the scope of each `if` statement.

You should declare `m` within the global scope of the method:

```
 public void mood()
 {
      string m = "default mood";
      // ...
 }
```

This will make it available to all child scopes (delimited by the curly braces), including each of the `if` statements.

In the code that you wrote initially, each time you wrote `string m` in a different scope, you were declaring a new variable called `m`. Each time you reached the end of the scope, that variable was destroyed. So when you got to the `WriteLine` statement, `m` effectively did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public void mood()
    {
        var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;
        string m;
        if (unhappiness < 5)
        {
            m = "Happy";
        }

        if (unhappiness <= 5 && 
            unhappiness <= 10)
        {
            m = "Okay";
        }

        if (unhappiness <= 11 &&
            unhappiness <= 15)
        {
            m = "Frustrated";
        }

        if (unhappiness <= 16)
        {
            m = "Mad";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

string m is defined *inside* your if-clauses. Also, you cannot return a string from your method, so i changed that :)

try

```
public string mood()
{
    var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;
    string m = string.Empty;

    if (unhappiness < 5)
    {
        m = "Happy";
    }

        // etc

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`m` doesn't exist. That's why you can't print it out or do anything with it. It doesn't exist. There is no such variable as `m`.

In some inner scopes, there happened to be several variables which were called `m`. But they were gone as long as the block in which they were defined was exited. Now they belong to a past which can not return. Their memories drifted away like drops in an ocean of garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issues you can do something like this:

```
public void mood()
{
  var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;
  string m = "Unknown";

  if (unhappiness < 5)
  {
    m = "Happy";
  }    
  else if (unhappiness >= 5 && unhappiness <= 10) // >= 5 not <= 5
  {
    m = "Okay";
  }
  else if (unhappiness > 11 && unhappiness <= 15) // > 10 or >= 11 not <= 11
  {
    m = "Frustrated";
  }
  else if (unhappiness >= 16) // assume it should be enything else
  {
    m = "Mad";
  }

  Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

- The definition of a variable and the usage of a variable has to occur in the same scope which is defined with the curly brackets { }. 
  So you can use m in the whole method mood but not outside the method mood in this case.
- if, else if comes in handy if you want to check something first and only if this results to false you want to check something else as a fallback.